# How to use OnSizeChanged to adapt MapView size?

Tags: android

I will try to be as clear as possible about I am trying to do. I have MapView which is first centered with the help of a Geopoint. 
Then, on top of this MapView, I have a LinearLayout that displays some information (the linearlayout covers partially the mapview). Its width varies with respects to its content. To keep my MapView centered, I would like to be able to get the width of linearlayout and then scroll the mapview of that width (using ScrollBy method) dynamically (each time the content of the linearlayout changes, the mapview is scrolled).

Here is what I have done so far :

An extract of my main.xml (it is used by my Activity) containing the mapview and the custom linearlayout :

```
<com.mikecorp.weather.tab.myframe
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:apiKey="@string/mapKey"
android:clickable="true"/>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<com.mikecorp.weather.tab.PanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/panel_weather_city"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FF4B4B4B" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/curr_weather_city"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="35dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
<View android:id="@+id/divider_h"
android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dp"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/curr_weather_desc"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
android:textSize="20dip"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingRight="20dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip" 
android:paddingBottom="20dip"
>               
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/curr_weather"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:layout_marginRight="20dip" >
</TextView>     
</com.mikecorp.weather.tab.PanelLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</com.mikecorp.weather.tab.myframe>
```

As you can see, I have a custom LinearLayout (PanelLayout) in which I have defined onLayout and onSizeChanged method in order to get the correct width of the layout. And this works fine. I can see the correct size.

```
public class PanelLayout extends LinearLayout {

private MapView mview;
private MapController controller;


public PanelLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public PanelLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    Log.d("TEST", "onLayout:" + String.format("%s-%d,%d,%d,%d", changed, l, t, r, b));
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    Log.d("TEST", "onSizeChanged:" + String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d", w, h, oldw, oldh));


    mview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    controller = mview.getController();
    controller.scrollBy(w, 0);
}
```

}

But, when I run the program, I have a NULL pointer exception (mview is null).

Before that, I tried to get the width (getWidth method) of the linearlayout in the activity itself, but it does not give  the right value since the linearlayout is not yet created. That's why, I decided to use onSizeChanged method in a custom LinearLayout. But, here, I am blocked.

I also thought about using a ViewGroup (and its onLayout method) that would contain my LinearLayout and my MapView but then I do not know when the width of the LinearLayout is changed.

Hope all of this makes sense for you guys, and that you will have enough information to help me ;)